# SpriteKit not respecting zPosition?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sprite-kit

What effect addChild and zPosition really have on a scene?

I mean this: suppose I do this

```
sprite1.zPosition = 50;
sprite2.zPosition = 10;
sprite3.zPosition = 30;
```

and later do this

```
[self addChild:sprite1];
[self addChild:sprite2];
[self addChild:sprite3];
```

according to SpriteKit and considering zPosition order, sprite1 should be rendered over sprite3 over sprite2 but spriteKit ignores that and renders 3 over 2 over 1.

am I missing something?

Comment: no more code. The code is just this. 3 layers with 3 different zPositions but are added in random order. SpriteKit should respect zPosition but it is not.

Comment: Try setting zPosition after addChild instead of before.

Comment: That should do no difference.

Comment: Can you make a test project for this case? Or just paste entire code from `SKScene`

Comment: It would help if you showed more code and then a screen shot of what is happening vs what should be happening.

Comment: You weren't by any chance using an SKCropNode, were you? I just ran into the same issue when adding children to one of them, sprites seemed like they were rendered at a random depth and the same code would result in different results despite all the zPositions being the same. I've gotten it to work by creating an empty node, adding it as the only child of my SKCropNode instance, and then adding all my other nodes to that node instead of the SKCropNode instance, but I definitely don't think I should have to do that.

Comment: I'm seeing all kinds of unpredictable behavior concerning the parent/child order and the zPositions. I suspect SpriteKit is buggy here (too). iOS 9.2.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If they have the same parent that would be true. In case they can different parents, the z order of parents is also taken into account.

The standard behavior for scene rendering follows a simple pair of rules:

1. A parent draws its content before rendering its children.
2. Children are rendered in the order in which they appear in the child
   array.

When you take z positions into account, here is how the node tree is rendered:

1. Each node’s global z position is calculated.
2. Nodes are drawn in order from smallest z value to largest z value.
3. If two nodes share the same z value, ancestors are rendered first,
   and siblings are rendered in child order.

You can find it well explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html) under Understanding the Drawing Order for a Node Tree

Comment: what will be true? 321 or 132? Spritekit is ignoring zPosition and rendering it 321.

Comment: 123 should be the result. As Jerome suggested we need more code to offer a better answer.

Comment: 123? you mean 1 on top or on bottom? so, what matters is the addChild order, not zPosition.

Comment: Please read the document I posted under "here". Z position matters, but if 2 nodes have same z position, add order is take into account. What you are experiencing is weird and could be caused by something else.

Comment: Sprite Kit draws all nodes with the same parent in order they were added to the parent, zPosition overrides this order. If the nodes have different parents, zPosition has no effect.

Answer (score 6):

In your game view controller, set the ignoresSiblingOrder property to false (or NO in objective-C).

```
let skView = self.view as SKView
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = false
```